# What are some good guides for setting up your first Apache HTTP Server?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, http

I am primarily a software developer and have limited experience setting up servers. I have been tasked with creating an HTTP/HTTPS server for use testing. What are some good guides/online resources for learning how to do a basic Apache HTTP set up? Nothing too complicated, just a good beginners guide. I am using Ubuntu Linux.

Edit: To be even more specific, here's a few things I definitely need to do:

1) Install the apache HTTP server into Ubuntu

2) Get it to host a server on 127.0.0.1 that just throws up a basic HTML page, nothing fancy, just hey here I am!

3) Be able to modify outgoing headers and read incoming headers

4) Be able to do all the same stuff in SSL/TLS

Comment: Windows or Linux?

Comment: Ubuntu Linux, sorry should have specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Howto Forge](http://www.howtoforge.com/) has plenty of hand-holding tutorials.

[LAMP on Ubuntu 10.4](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-10.04-lamp)

Answer (score 0):

It is a very boring answer but you can't really go wrong with http://httpd.apache.org/docs/

I think it is well written and should be able to guide you through regardless of level.

Answer (score 0):

Also the ubuntu documentation has a page on this subject. See here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Answer (score 0):

Most important, make sure it isn't reachable over the interwebs for the start ;-)